# Total time execution of a query

Tags: oracle

I`m trying to obtain the total time of a query execution

I have this query but not allways get the output that I hope, For example for the same parallel 4 execution of a query sometimes I obtain 5 rows (query controller and 4 parallels) but other times I only obtain 2 parallel process result (the parallels processes only open in the same instance)

Is this query correct or I need to add something more?

```
select inst_id, sql_exec_id,session_id, QC_SESSION_ID,program,sql_id,sql_plan_hash_value,round((count(*))/60/60, 2) as Horas 
from    gv$active_session_history ash
where   sql_id='7u0wv0g5r3y2n' 
and sql_exec_id is not null       
group by    inst_id, sql_exec_id,session_id,QC_SESSION_ID,program,sql_id,sql_plan_hash_value      
order by    2,1,4,5 desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

I use set events 10046, for the explain plan and 10053 for the waits.
Once you run the queries that you want timings for, assuming that you are using 10g/11g/12c go to the diag trace folder, find your trace files and run tkprof against the trace files.

```
ALTER SESSION SET tracefile_identifier = 'test_plan1';
ALTER SESSION SET EVENTS '10053 trace name context forever, level 1';
ALTER SESSION SET EVENTS '10046 trace name context forever, level 12';

/*
run your queries here
*/

ALTER SESSION SET EVENTS '10053 trace name context OFF';
ALTER SESSION SET EVENTS '10046 trace name context OFF';


go to the <diag>/rdbms/<sidname>/<sidname>/trace directory
tkprof <in file name> <out file name> waits=yes explain=syste/<pwd>
```

This will give really good information about how the queries ran, how long, 
how much logical/physical IO, explain plan and waits. Plus you don't need 
any optional components to get the information.

```
-- use logging package to log and not reraise errors
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER application_logon_trace
       AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE
DECLARE
   v_db_user VARCHAR2(64) := SYS_CONTEXT ('SESSION_USERID', 'PROXY_USER' );
   v_host    VARCHAR2(64) := SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV',        'HOST'    );
   v_ddl_cmd VARCHAR2(2000);
BEGIN
-- You can have an IF clause that will only turn on logging for certain users if you like
-- or you can only log sessions coming from certain servers/pcs if you want.
   IF INSTR(v_host, '.') > 0
   THEN
      v_host := SUBSTR( v_host, 1, INSTR(v_host, '.')-1);
   END IF;

   v_ddl_cmd := 'ALTER SESSION SET tracefile_identifier = ''application_logon_trace_'|| v_db_user || '_' || v_host ||'''';
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( v_ddl_cmd );
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_ddl_cmd;

   v_ddl_cmd := 'ALTER SESSION SET EVENTS=''10046 trace name context forever, level 12''';
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( v_ddl_cmd );
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_ddl_cmd;

   v_ddl_cmd := 'ALTER SESSION SET EVENTS=''10053 trace name context forever, level  1''';
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( v_ddl_cmd );
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_ddl_cmd;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL; -- feel free to call you favorite error logging package here.
END;
/
```

Comment: Hi, I can't create any objects in database. I have to monitor only with queries. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have 13c Oracle Enterprise Manager with the diagnostics and tuning pack? If so you should just tune the queries with that or AWR or ASH reports. Otherwise, you are going to have a tough time figuring out what is happening. If you can pull out the queries that seem like they might be slow, you could run them in sql plus and use set events like I mentioned earlier. But it won't be easy.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the total execution time of a query, then use the view that contains the total execution time of queries.

```
select elapsed_time from gv$sql where sql_id = '7u0wv0g5r3y2n';
```

Note that this returns the cumulative execution time of parallel processes, not the wall-clock time.

Comment: Hi, I use the active_session_history because I want to know the total time of each execution in a determinated window of time.